# Recursively apply a function to elements of an array spark dataFrame

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dictionary

I wrote the following function which concatenates two strings and adds them in a dataframe new column:

```
def idCol(firstCol: String, secondCol: String, IdCol: String = FUNCTIONAL_ID): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn(IdCol,concat(col(firstCol),lit("."),col(secondCol))).dropDuplicates(IdCol)
}
```

My aim is to replace the use of different strings by one array of strings, and then define the new column from the concatenation of these different elements of the array. I am using an array in purpose in order to have a mutable data collection in case the number of elements to concatenate changes. 
Do you have any idea about how to do this 
So the function would be changed as :

```
def idCol(cols:Array[String], IdCol: String = FUNCTIONAL_ID): DataFrame = {

 df.withColumn(IdCol,concat(col(cols(0)),lit("."),col(cols(1))).dropDuplicates(IdCol)
    }
```

I want to bypass the cols(0), cols(1) and do a generic transformation which takes all elements of array and seperate them by the char "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws` which has the following definition:

> ```
> def concat_ws(sep: String, exprs: Column*): Column
> ```

You need to convert your column names which are in `String` to `Column` type:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def idCol(cols:Array[String], IdCol: String = FUNCTIONAL_ID): DataFrame = {    
    val concatCols = cols.map(col(_))    
    df.withColumn(IdCol, concat_ws(".", concatCols : _*) ).dropDuplicates(IdCol)   
}
```